# How to print text output MDTextField kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

> the problem is when i put some text he didnt print output in console what the problem please

```py
sm = ScreenManager()

screen_helper = '''
ScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:

<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'MenuScreen'
    MDTextField:
       id: pwd
'''
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
 
class MenuScreen(Screen):
    def printing(self):
        print (self.ids.pwd.text)
```

Comment: Your cod does not call the `printing()` method.

Comment: can you give me exemple please

Comment: You must post a [mcve] in order to see where that code should go.